Can we define a stopping time with the initial condition of a Markov chain?
Let $X_n$ be a discrete-time Markov chain on a countable state space (for simplicity let $X$ be a simple random walk). If I define $\tau=\inf\{n\ge 0: X_n=X_0-1\}$, then I think $\tau$ is a stopping time since the event $\{\tau\le k\}$ is completely determined by the history of $X$ up to $k$.
However, it seems that we cannot use the Markov property. If it does, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E_0(\tau|X_1)1_{X_1=1}=(\mathbb E_1(\tau)+1)1_{X_1=1},
\end{align}
which sounds strange to me because the $\tau$ in the left-hand side is the first hitting time to $-1$, but the $\tau$ in the right-hand side is the first hitting time to 0.
I am definitely misunderstanding something.

The Markov property says, roughly, that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X_t, X_{t+1}, \dots) \mid X_0, \dots, X_t] = \mathbb{E}[f(X_t, X_{t+1}, \dots) \mid X_t]
$$
for all functions $f$ where the expectations are finite (e.g. all bounded $f$ are included).
The issue is that in general, $\tau$ cannot be written as $f(X_t, X_{t+1}, \dots)$ if $t > 0$, because $\tau$ depends on $X_0$. So the Markov property doesn't apply directly to this case.
That said, I bet it's true that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau \mid X_0, \dots, X_t] \, \mathbf{1}_{\tau > t} = \mathbb{E}[\tau \mid X_0, X_t] \, \mathbf{1}_{\tau > t},
$$
but I'll leave verifying this (or finding a counterexample!) as an exercise.
(To make this all more formal, replace "expressible as a function of" with "measurable in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by".)

It might be helpful to get a little formal. A typical sample point is a sequence $\omega=(\omega_0,\omega_1,\ldots)$ of states, and $X_n(\omega) =\omega_n$. The stopping time $\tau$ is
$$
\tau(\omega) :=
\min\{n\ge 0: \omega_n=\omega_0-1\}.
$$
Notice that $\Bbb P_0[\tau =T_{-1}]=1$,
where, for an integer $b$,
$$
T_{b}(\omega) :=\min\{n\ge 1: \omega_n=b\}.
$$
On the event $\{X_1=1\}$ you have $T_{-1}(\omega) =1+T_{-2}(\theta\omega)$, where $\theta$ is the time shift
$$
\theta\omega =\theta(\omega_0,\omega_1,\ldots)=(\omega_1,\omega_2\ldots)
$$
So, with $\Bbb P_0$ probability 1, on the event $\{X_1=1\}$,
$$
\Bbb E_0(\tau\mid X_1) =1+\Bbb E_1(T_{-1}),
$$
by the Markov property at time $1$.
Notice that when $X_0(\omega) =1$, $T_{-1}(\omega) \not=\tau(\omega)=T_0(\omega)$.
